# CentOS 7: PCS Pacemaker Corosync Active/Active HAProxy dependency

Tags: haproxy, cluster, pacemaker, corosync

I am trying to setup PCS for HAProxy on CentOS7 in an active/active configuration.
I've done active/active before, but I am not familiar with constraints and dependency groups.

So far so good:

```
 2 nodes configured
 4 resources configured

 Online: [ HOST1 HOST2 ]

 Full list of resources:

  Clone Set: VIPHA-clone [VIPHA] (unique)
      VIPHA:0     (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started HOST2
      VIPHA:1     (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started HOST1
  Clone Set: haproxy-clone [haproxy]
      Started: [ HOST2 HOST1 ]
```

However, now I'd like to add a constraint that HAPRoxy must be running in order for the IP to be served by a host:

> pcs constraint order haproxy-clone then VIPHA-clone

The problem with this is, HAProxy will never start because it cannot bind to the IP unless it is started first.

How would I set this up so that:

1. pcs will take the IP offline on a host if a health check (i.e. haproxy process running) fails?
2. pcs will only bring the IP up if a health check (i.e. haproxy process running) succeeds?

   - If this isn't possible as described above, start at same time and behave as #1

I appreciate any input. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I listen on a wildcard in haproxy.cfg

```
bind *:443
```

instead of

```
bind myvip:443
```

This way haproxy resource can run all the time whether the node has VIP resource or not. If node gets a VIP, haproxy will respond on it immediately.

The obvious side effect is that haproxy listens on all it's IP addresses not only on VIP.

If a port number conflicts (for example I need a differently configured port 443 on another IP or VIP), I define it as `bind *:9443` and then put it behind a DNAT.

Comment: Very well yes that does the trick for binding HAPRoxy. Do you know how to STONITH a node or restart haproxy if haproxy crashes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not tied to pacemaker/corosync, the behavior you describe can be achieved with `opensvc`, using the service configuration file below :

```
[DEFAULT]
id = 84327b87-13f6-4d32-b90a-a7fad87a8d92
nodes = server1 server2
flex_min_nodes = 2
topology = flex
orchestrate = ha
monitor_action = freezestop

[ip#vip]
ipname@server1 = 192.168.100.240
ipname@server2 = 192.168.100.241
ipdev = br0
monitor = true

[app#haproxy]
type = simple
start = /sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
restart = 1
monitor = true
```

Explanations :

`[DEFAULT` section is the global configuration settings :

- `id = ....` unique service id, automatically generated at service creation time (`svcmgr -s myservice create`, and then `svcmgr -s myservice edit config`)
- `nodes = server1 server2` mean we are running a 2 nodes `opensvc` cluster
- `flex_min_nodes = 2` tell that we expect the service run at least 2 instances. In this 2 nodes cluster, we will have 1 instance per node.
- `topology = flex` specify that we are running an active/active service topology
- `orchestrate = ha` tells that the service have to be automatically managed by the `opensvc` daemon
- `monitor_action = freezestop` is used to force the behaviour when a critical resource goes down (like a haproxy process crash or kill). If this happens, the 
  `opensvc` daemon has to take a decision. 3 possible parameters :

  - `freezestop` : the local service instance is stopped, and put in frozen state.
  - `reboot` : the node is rebooted.
  - `crash` : the node is crashed.

`[ip#vip]` : is used to declare the service vip :

- on `server1` the ip `192.168.100.240` will be configured on interface `br0` at service start
- on `server2` the ip `192.168.100.241` will be configured on interface `br0` at service start
- `monitor = true` tells `opensvc` agent that this resource is critical (if it goes down, trigger the service `monitor_action`)

`[app#haproxy]` : describes the application stuff :

- `type = simple` specify that the service manage a single process application (non forking daemon)
- `start = /sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` is the command to run when the service start
- `restart = 1` tells the `opensvc` daemon to try to restart `1` time this resource if it goes down.
- `monitor = true` haproxy is a critical resource. If it goes down, try to restart 1 time due to the previous parameter, and if it fails, then trigger the `monitor_action`

As the service rely on vip, you are not obliged to bind *:443, but only the service vip.

About your question on restart/stonith if haproxy goes down, just put a `restart = 1` in the `[app#haproxy]` to try a restart, and also a `monitor_action = crash` in the `DEFAULT` section. This way, 1 restart is tried, and if this does not work, node is crashed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like your explanation, but a switch to opensvc first requires extensive testing and familiarization. I will look into this as an option when this comes up for re-evaluation!